# Invoking wsclient_service_load function in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm trying to invoke this function in a `Drupal` custom module:

```
wsclient_service_load('my_web_service');
```

And it returns an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wsclient_service_load() in...

But if I invoke the same function from `page.tpl.php` it works fine.

I must being missing something really basic.

Hope someone can enlight me.

Thanks

Comment: Check that you're not missing any includes

Comment: Any sugestions where to start looking?

Comment: You can always ask at http://drupal.stackexchange.com or search on php drupal API where is that that function is implemented.

Comment: That function is from a contributed module - Web Services Client